# Synchronicity with parse cloud code

Tags: concurrency, parse-server

I am building an 'uber fox X' app, using parse server as a backend.

My problem: when there is a pending request, many 'drivers' can offer to fullfill it. When a 'driver' chooses to to so, I need to ensure that the request has not been taken by another driver.

I.e: I need the operation of assigning a request to a driver to be atomic, so that a second request always knows that a first has arrived

Comment: Make use of parse live query to achieve that.

Comment: @Cliffordwh how will that solve the problem.  I think that the problem he's trying to solve is that he wants to commit to mongo that a driver is associated with an order.  But there's not a parse api to verify versioning on update, so I don't think it can be done (though adding this would be super good and possible).